# Redirect Application to error page when docker image is not available

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, docker-machine

Our requirement is during the deployment or for any downtime if we delete the docker image.
Is it possible to for us to redirect the user to static error page from load balance level?

So, If we want to take application down i.e. delete the docker image using kubernatics. when we delete the docker image then wen hit the application URL then we get bad get way message in browser. So, instated of Bad Request we want to show them Static error page.

Comment: if you delete the docker image from where ? from registry ? The k8s application will only make a pull depending on the Imagepillpolicy defined in your yaml. Could you please elaborate the scenario a bit more.

Comment: If you are using nginx-ingress you can use a default application. If the requested service id down the ingress will redirect to a default service... You must have a default service deployed. It works for you?